# .NET Core argument decimal error on Ubuntu terminal

Tags: c#, ubuntu, .net-core, parameters, arguments

I've made an application in .net core that accept 2 decimal values as arguments.  (3.1 core)

Example:

```
./MyApp 5.100 53.30
```

This works perfectly on my Windows system when testing. However when i publish it to my ubuntu server it doesn't see the dots in my decimal value.

When i print the values after giving them the application in Ubuntu sees them as:
`5100 5330` instead of `5.100 53.30`.

I have no clue what i did wrong. Would appreciate it if someone knows the answer to this !

edit:

I have tried to convert them with this:

```
decimal Lat = 0;
decimal.TryParse(args[1], out Lat)
```

Also tried converting with:

```
decimal Lat = 0;
Lat = Convert.ToDecimal(args[1])
```

both result into the dots being removed

the dots are only being removed AFTER parsing. 
printing them before parsing works fine.

Comment: How do you convert the strings to numbers? So please show your code for parsing the values and also printing the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ubuntu system mostlikly has a culture setting that dosen't have a decimal-point in numbers. 
For example in english would it be `5.10` but in langauges like german it would be `5,10` so use the overload for `TryParse` that accepts a `IFormatProvider` to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to parse the string.

So just do

```cs
decimal lat = 0;
decimal.TryParse(args[1], NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out lat);
```

Comment: Good one, i tested it but now it gives comma's instead of dots, definitely has to do with culture

Comment: @sasa you also need to use the InvariantCulture for outputing the data